# How to limit the chrome size in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-plugin, flutter-desktop

Is there any way we can limit the size of Chrome flutter_web app?
Like we can do in [flutter_desktop](https://dev.to/_regnex/how-to-limit-window-resize-in-flutter-desktop-40d8)

```
  if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS) {
    setWindowTitle('App title');
    setWindowMinSize(const Size(700, 500));
    setWindowMaxSize(Size.infinite);
  }
```

Plugin for flutter desktop :  [window_size](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/window_size)

Comment: found any thing?